# Showing results from two different XML files in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

So I am trying to pull results from two different XML files using XSLT in order to show a Restaurant Review. I have  Restaurant details in allRestaurants.xml and have all of the reviews for these restaurants in allReviews.xml. I have currently stored a  tag against each restaurant, and the reviews are each associated with a specific restaurant as well, so carry the same  tag. I need to build a page that takes the restaurant with ID 1 and beneath is show the reviews for that restaurant. The reviews are stored with the exactly the same 1 as per below. Please help.

**allRestaurants.xml**

```
<restaurants>
<restaurant>
    <restaurant_id>1</restaurant_id>
    <name>The Jackaroo</name>
    <street_address>107-109 Darlinghurst Road</street_address>
    <postcode>2011</postcode>
    <city>Sydney</city>
    <state>NSW</state>
    <country>Australia</country>
    <email>info@jackaroo.com.au</email>
    <telephone>93322244</telephone>
    <stars>3</stars>
</restaurant>
<restaurant>
    <restaurant_id>2</restaurant_id>
    <name>Four Seasons restaurant Sydney</name>
    <street_address>199 George Street</street_address>
    <postcode>2000</postcode>
    <city>Sydney</city>
    <state>NSW</state>
    <country>Australia</country>
    <email>info@sydneyfourseasons.com.au</email>
    <telephone>92503100</telephone>
    <stars>5</stars>
</restaurant>
</restaurants>
```

**allReviews.xml**

```
<reviews>
<review id="1">
    <restaurant_id>1</restaurant_id>
    <author_id>1</author_id>
    <headline>Clean Bare-Bones Hostel</headline>
    <details>
        Example text here
    </details>
    <rating>3</rating>
    <date>1388782853</date>
</review>
<review id="2">
    <restaurant_id>1</restaurant_id>
    <author_id>3</author_id>
    <headline>Wouldn't Recommend</headline>
    <details>
        Example text here
    </details>
    <rating>2</rating>
    <date>1368748800</date>
</review>
<review id="3">
    <restaurant_id>2</restaurant_id>
    <author_id>2</author_id>
    <headline>Overall I Enjoyed</headline>
    <details>
        Example text here
    </details>
    <rating>4</rating>
    <date>1378788850</date>
</review>
</reviews>
```

I thought maybe merging them into one XML file like so would do the trick, but even then, I'm not sure where to start:

**oneHotel.xml**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="oneHotel.xsl"?>
<list>
    <entry name="allHotels.xml" />
    <entry name="reviews.xml" />
</list>
```

This is as far as I got in the XSLT doc, and am drawing a massive blank. I don't even know where to start:

**oneHotel.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:copy-of name="restaurant" select="document('allRestaurants.xml') 
       /restaurants/restaurant[restaurant_id=1]"/>
<xsl:copy-of name="reviews" select="document('allReviews.xml') 
       /reviews/review[restaurant_id=1]"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="document('allRestaurants.xml') 
           /restaurants/restaurant[restaurant_id=1]"/>
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
</xsl:choose>
<h2><xsl:value-of select="$restaurant/name"/></h2>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-reviews" select="'allReviews.xml'"/>

<xsl:key name="review-by-restaurant-id" match="review" use="restaurant_id" />

<xsl:template match="/restaurants">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Restaurant Reviews</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="restaurant"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="restaurant">
    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </h2>
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="restaurant_id" />
    <!-- switch context to lookup document in order to use key -->
    <xsl:for-each select="document($path-to-reviews)">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('review-by-restaurant-id', $id)">
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="headline"/>
            </h3>
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="details"/>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes that you are instructing your XSLT processor to process the `allRestaurants.xml` document and passing the path to the `allReviews.xml` document as a parameter.

You didn't tell us what you want your final result to look like, so I just made up a very basic page.

Comment: Thanks for that. So how would I filter out the restaurants and reviews that I didn't want? For example, lets say I only wanted to retrieve restaurant_id "1" and its corresponding reviews?

Comment: @umgrand Change `<xsl:apply-templates select="restaurant"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="restaurant[restaurant_id=1]"/>`.